# how to save data frame in Mongodb in spark using custom value for _id column

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val transctionSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("School_id", StringType, true),
      StructField("School_Year", StringType, true),
      StructField("Run_Type", StringType, true),
      StructField("Bus_No", StringType, true),
      StructField("Route_Number", StringType, true),
      StructField("Reason", StringType, true),
      StructField("Occurred_On", DateType, true),

      StructField("Number_Of_Students_On_The_Bus", IntegerType, true)))
 val dfTags = sparkSession.read.option("header", true).schema(transctionSchema).
      option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMddhhmm")
      .csv("src/main/resources/9_bus-breakdown-and-delays_case_study.csv").
      toDF("School_id", "School_Year", "Run_Type", "Bus_No", "Route_Number", "Reason", "Occurred_On", "Number_Of_Students_On_The_Bus")

    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val writeConfig = WriteConfig(Map("collection" -> "bus_Details", "writeConcern.w" -> "majority"), Some(WriteConfig(sparkSession)))
    dfTags.show(5)
```

I have a data frame with the column: School_id/School_year/Run_Type/Bus_No/Route_No/Reason/Occured_on. I want to save this data in mongo DB collection **bus_Details** such that **_id** in mongo collection holds the data from **School_id** column of the Data Frame.

I saw some post where it was suggested to define a collection as :But it is not working

```
properties: {
         School_id: {
            bsonType: "string",
            id:"true"
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         }
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a duplicate column names as `_id` in your dataframe like:

```
val dfToSave = dfTags.withColumn("_id", $"School_id")
```

And then save this to mongodb